# weakly open subset in $M[0,1]$ (the space of finite measures on $[0,1]$)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

I came across this question when reading Lynch and Sethuraman (1987): Large deviations for processes with independent increments.

Let $M[0,1]$ be the space of finite nonnegative measures on $[0,1]$ endowed with the weak topology. (Actually this is the weak*-topology in functional analysis.) $G$ is a weakly-open subset of $M[0,1]$ and $f\in G$. Given a partition $\mathcal P=\{0=t_0<t_1<...<t_k=1\}$, let $A_i=[0,t_1]$ if $i=1$ and $A_i=(t_{i-1},t_i]$ if $i=2,...,k$.

Then in the proof of Theorem 4.2, it says that there exists a $\delta>0$ and a partition $\mathcal P=\{0=t_0<t_1<...<t_k=1\}$ consisting of continuity points of $f$ such that the neighborhood 
$N_{\mathcal{P},\delta}=\{g: \max_{i}|g(A_i)-f(A_i)|<\delta\}$ of $f$ is contained in $G$.

My question is why is the above statement true. I was confused about it. Even if the measures on each $A_i$ are close, there is no way to guarantee that the distribution functions at these points are also close. I think it is possible to construct a measure $g$ in $N_{\mathcal{P},\delta}$ but $\max_i|g(t_i)-f(t_i)|$ could still be large. Then it seems that $N_{\mathcal{P},\delta}$ is not contained in $G$ no matter what partition and $\delta$ are.

Comment: What are the continuity points of a measure $f \in G \subset M[0,1]$?

Comment: I should clarify that $f(t)$ is the distribution function of $f\in G$. So it has countably many discontinuity points. The paper says that there exists such a partition but does not specify what the points are.